# Slackware on Virtual Box: Where do i find /dev/hdx?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, slackware

I'm trying to install Linux (Slackware) on Virtual Box using the steps provided [here](http://www.bnetweb.org/how-to/install-slackware-on-virtualbox/).

After setting up virtual box and logging into pre-install as 'root', Step 17 tries to partition the disk using `cfdisk /dev/hda`

Host OS: Windows XP

This path does not exist; Any thoughts on where I may locate this path?

Comment: OK, turns out what I have on my virtual box is /dev/sda instead of /dev/hda ... Any idea why it says /dev/sda though? The host machine does not possess any SATA drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libata made all the ATA devices fall under the SCSI subsystem, so they're `/dev/sdX` now.